Codeigniter with nginx sub path
Objective:
Using nginx to server normal html pages AND codeigniter pages. For example, get example.com to show /var/www/html/index.html and example.com/ci to show stuff from codeigniter/public, so that example.com/ci/home would show the homepage loaded by codeigniter.
Attempts:
With this config example.com leads to the welcome page from CI and example.com/home leads to the homepage from codeigniter.
example.com/home > homepage
    root  /var/www/html/AWD/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

With this config example.com/ci leads to a 404 not found from codeigniter in Views/pages/Error.php but example.com/ci/home leads to Views/errors/html/error_404.php.
example.com/ci/home > 404 not found
    root  /var/www/html/;

    location /ci {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /AWD/public/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

And if i set it to location /home then it shows home fine
example.com/home > homepage
    root  /var/www/html/;

    location /home {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /AWD/public/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

but i dont want to set every single path on nginx, i want to give codeigniter a root on a sub path. ive got this to work once but accidentally deleted the nginx file and the .htaccess inside public.
Oh and I have another part serving the php:
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi:
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

And this is my .htaccess inside public:
# Disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteBase /uni/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end

